# Could this sentence be better rephrased?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, relative-clauses

その婦人たちは、両親が昼間工場で働いている子供たちの世話をしています。

The 働いている子供たち part sounds like "working kids" so maybe another particle could be put between 働いている and 子供たち? Or a comma?

Comment: そのままでいいような気が・・・

Comment: @Chocolate はい、僕は考えすぎているでしょうね

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「その婦人{ふじん}たちは、両親{りょうしん}が昼間工場{ひるまこうじょう}で働{はたら}いている子供{こども}たちの世話{せわ}をしています。」

There is nothing wrong with this sentence.  It is grammatical and natural-sounding.

In the relative clause construct 「両親が昼間工場で働いている子供たち」, 「両親が昼間工場で働いている」 modifies 「子供たち」.

> The 働いている子供たち part sounds like "working kids" so maybe another particle could be put between 働いている and 子供たち? Or a comma?

No particle can be placed there and a comma would be out of the question as well.  I suggest that you review the Japanese relative clause because its structure is ***completely*** different from that of the relative clause in European languages.

If you had to rephrase the sentence for a good reason (though I have no idea what that reason could be), you could say:

> 「その婦人たちは、両親が昼間工場で働いている**家庭{かてい}の**子供たちの世話をしています。」

Comment: `～家庭の～` <-- おおお・・うまいなー ﾊﾟﾁﾊﾟﾁ

Comment: Yeah I haven't studied relative clauses (or grammar at all, Japanese grammar is so frightening) in depth yet, just vocab